# Messages stop being sent into the channel

Tags: node.js, events, discord.js

I'm trying to build a Discord bot that interacts with users after they post a message. But I struggle to make it work. It might have to do with my asynchronous coding knowledge being poor; here's a reduced version of what I did nonetheless.

```
[requires...]

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS", "GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

[var inits...]

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if(!message.author.bot){

    if(message.content.match(/\.help/)){
        mySend(message.channel, 'help');
    } else if(message.content.match(/\.begin game \d+/)){
        const matcher = message.content.match(/\d+/);
        const endScore = parseInt(matcher[0]);

        mySend(message.channel, 'preparing game ...');// <-- properly sent

        /**
         * Load
         */
        load(message).then(() => {
            parsing = false;
            
            mySend(message.channel, 'game start');// <-- not properly sent
            startedGame = true;
            gameChannel = message.channel;
            target = new EventTarget();
            
            playGame(message, endScore);
            mySend(message.channel, 'end game');
            startedGame = false;
            gameChannel = null;
        });
    } else if(startedGame && message.channel.id == gameChannel.id){ // parse messages sent in the gameChannel
        // dispatch answer event
        console.log('received: '+message.content);
        target.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('answer', { detail: message }));
    }
  }
});

async function load(message){
    const selectedA = list.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0,50);
    let selectedB = await getB(selectedA);
    for(let i = 0;i<selectedB.length;++i) {
        await getLyrics(selectedB[i].elem, message).then(
            response => gameElems.push({
                [obj things...]
            })
        );
    }
}
```

(note: `mySend()` is just a `channel.send()` with personal emotes parsing.)

When debugging this code step by step, I saw that the message that is `// <-- not properly sent` is being sent too, just nothing happens anymore in the channel.

Any clue why it behaves this way? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"not properly sent"* - what do you mean not properly?

Comment: I mean that, when I execute it step by step, everything *looks like* it is sent, but it is not received by the server since I can't read it in Discord. So it is *a fortiori* not *properly* sent, and maybe *not sent at all*, but I can't know this.